# How to get all purchases from Google in app billing?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I need to get all the items purchased from in app billing from google play. I can see the function I want

```
getAllOwnedSkus()
```

in the class below provided by google but it's visibility is not public. I could simply change it to public but there has to be another way to get all the owned skus by the user?

```
public class Inventory {
    Map<String,SkuDetails> mSkuMap = new HashMap<String,SkuDetails>();
    Map<String,Purchase> mPurchaseMap = new HashMap<String,Purchase>();

    Inventory() { }

    /** Returns the listing details for an in-app product. */
    public SkuDetails getSkuDetails(String sku) {
        return mSkuMap.get(sku);
    }

    /** Returns purchase information for a given product, or null if there is no purchase. */
    public Purchase getPurchase(String sku) {
        return mPurchaseMap.get(sku);
    }

    /** Returns whether or not there exists a purchase of the given product. */
    public boolean hasPurchase(String sku) {
        return mPurchaseMap.containsKey(sku);
    }

    /** Return whether or not details about the given product are available. */
    public boolean hasDetails(String sku) {
        return mSkuMap.containsKey(sku);
    }

    /**
     * Erase a purchase (locally) from the inventory, given its product ID. This just
     * modifies the Inventory object locally and has no effect on the server! This is
     * useful when you have an existing Inventory object which you know to be up to date,
     * and you have just consumed an item successfully, which means that erasing its
     * purchase data from the Inventory you already have is quicker than querying for
     * a new Inventory.
     */
    public void erasePurchase(String sku) {
        if (mPurchaseMap.containsKey(sku)) mPurchaseMap.remove(sku);
    }

    /** Returns a list of all owned product IDs. */
    List<String> getAllOwnedSkus() {
        return new ArrayList<String>(mPurchaseMap.keySet());
    }

    /** Returns a list of all owned product IDs of a given type */
    List<String> getAllOwnedSkus(String itemType) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Purchase p : mPurchaseMap.values()) {
            if (p.getItemType().equals(itemType)) result.add(p.getSku());
        }
        return result;
    }

    /** Returns a list of all purchases. */
    List<Purchase> getAllPurchases() {
        return new ArrayList<Purchase>(mPurchaseMap.values());
    }

    void addSkuDetails(SkuDetails d) {
        mSkuMap.put(d.getSku(), d);
    }

    void addPurchase(Purchase p) {
        mPurchaseMap.put(p.getSku(), p);
    }
}
```

but it's visibility is not public? I can simply change this but is there another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are talking about `IabHelper` application from Google. This is not the official API, but just an example of how you can use In-app Billing API. You can change this app in any way you want to. There is only one drawback in changing it. If Google releases a new update to this app, you will need to merge changes back into your code. The less changes you have, the easier will be the merge. Making method `public` is not a big deal in that respect.